# Секция RPATH в elf-файле

Tags: linux, g++, elf, ld, линковка

Я собираю исполняемый файл к которому линкую статическую и динамическую библиотеку(`foo` и `boo`соответственно). Эти библиотеки подтягиваются из репозитория в папку с исходниками:

```
testApp/
      foo
      boo
      src
      CMakeLists.txt
```

И когда я получаю `testApp` команда `readelf -d testApp` выдает мне следующее:

```
   Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [boo.so]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/anton/project/testApp/foo:/home/anton/project/testApp/boo]
```

Зачем в секции `RPATH` указывается путь до статической библиотеки, она же не нужна для запуска приложения?

Можно ли сделать так чтобы секция `RPATH` была пустой? Так как эти пути имею смысл только на машине где происходит сборка.

Comment: Сколько чужого софта перебрал из роутеров..) у всех путь на домашнюю папку)

Comment: Вот в том то и вопрос, либо есть возможность редактировать эту секцию, либо перед компиляцией все зависимости перед компиляцией кладутся в `/usr/lib/`

Comment: а стрип не вычищает?

Comment: Что такое стрип?

Comment: man strip ;) вычищает лишние символы из бинарника

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить (или изменить) RPATH можно через утилиты *chrpath* или *PatchELF*:

`$ chrpath -d testApp`

или

`$ patchelf --shrink-rpath testApp`

Также можно воспользоваться библиотекой LIEF и Python:

```py
import lief

binary = lief.parse("testApp")
binary.remove(lief.ELF.DYNAMIC_TAGS.RPATH)
binary.write("testApp_nopath")
```